# JSP: Insert not functioning (SQLSERVER)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, sql-server, jsp

Good day. I'm a beginner at JSP and I got a Daily Sales Monitoring as a project. I have done my research and I've made my first CRUD jsp program function, but when I added a lot of columns, the insert didn't work(delete and view still works). There are no visible errors, but as soon as it redirects on the read page, the newest data won't load.

I've tried looking for the mistake on all angles but I just can't seem to find it. I tried counting all the columns, renamed some instances, but it still won't function. Can you help me on my problem? It's my first time asking here, and I can't seem to find the answer on the previous questions. All replies will be appreciated.

By the way, I use Netbeans IDE 8.1 and Microsoft SQL Server

**AddNew.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add New</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Add New</h1>
        <div style="width: 900px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
            <form action="JSP/ManagerAddNew.jsp" method="post">                
                Station:
                <input type="text" name="station" style="width: 200px" value="South Area Auto Gas Corp. - Kawit" readonly><br><br>
                <!--Title:<br>
                <input type="text" name="title" style="width: 200px" ><br>
                -->
                Date:
                <input type="date" name="date" style="width: 200px"><br><br>
                <!--Description:<br>
                <input type="text" name="description" style="width: 200px"><br>
                -->
                Shift: 
                <select name="shift">
                    <option value="World">GY</option>
                    <option value="World">AM</option>
                    <option value="Tech">PM</option>
                </select><br><br>                  
                Product: 
                <select name="product">
                    <option value="World">LPG</option>
                    <option value="Tech">Diesel</option>
                    <option value="World">Unleaded</option>
                    <option value="Tech">Premium</option>                    
                </select><br><br>
                U/Price:
                <input type="text" name="uprice" style="width: 200px">
                No. of Transaction:
                <input type="text" name="nooftrans" style="width: 50px"><br><br>
                Cashier:
                <input type="text" name="cashier" style="width: 300px"><br><br>
                Tank 1:
                <input type="text" name="tank1level" placeholder="gauge" style="width: 50px">
                <input type="text" name="tank1liters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br><br>
                Tank 2:
                <input type="text" name="tank2level" placeholder="gauge" style="width: 50px">
                <input type="text" name="tank2liters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br><br><br><br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Liters</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cash:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cashliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cashamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Card:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cardliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="cardamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Charge:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="chargeliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="chargeamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>G.C:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="gcliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="gcamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fleet Card:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fleetliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fleetamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tapping:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="tappingliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="tappingamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hosefill:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="hosefillliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="hosefillamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Calibration: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="calibrateliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="calibrateamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gross: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="grossliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="grossamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>                     
                </table>
                
                <br><br>
                Deposit Amount:<br>
                <input type="text" name="cashdepoamt" placeholder="gauge" style="width: 100px">
                <input type="text" name="checkdepoamt" placeholder="liters" style="width: 100px">
                <input type="text" name="variance" placeholder="liters" style="width: 100px"><br><br>

                <!--
                START NOTE: ADD TO EDIT LATER
                -->
                User ID:
                <input type="text" name="userid" style="width: 300px"><br><br>
                Transmit
                <input type="text" name="transmit" style="width: 300px"><br><br>
                Transmit Date:
                <input type="date" name="transmitdate" style="width: 300px"><br><br>
                Create Date:
                <input type="date" name="createdate" style="width: 300px"><br><br>

                
                <!--
                NOTE: ADD TO EDIT LATER
                -->
                
                <!--Detail:<br>
                <textarea name="detail" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></textarea><br>
                -->
                <!--
                Category: 
                <select name="category">
                    <option value="World">World</option>
                    <option value="Tech">Tech</option>
                    <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
                </select><br>
                -->
                <!--Image:<br>
                <input type="text" name="image" style="width: 200px"><br>
                -->
                <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <!--Complete Interface Addnew.-->
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**ManagerAddNew.jsp**

```js
<%-- 
    Document   : ManagerAddNew
    Created on : Aug 8, 2015, 10:38:33 PM
    Author     : Thang
--%>

<%@page import="dao.DataAccess"%>
<%@page import="model.News"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Date"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% 
            String station = request.getParameter("station"); //
            String date = request.getParameter("date"); //
            String shift = request.getParameter("shift"); //
            String uprice = request.getParameter("uprice"); //
            String cashliters = request.getParameter("cashliters");//
            String cashamt = request.getParameter("cashamt");//
            String cardliters = request.getParameter("cardliters");//
            String cardamt = request.getParameter("cardamt");//
            String chargeliters = request.getParameter("chargeliters");//
            String chargeamt = request.getParameter("chargeamt");//
            String gcliters = request.getParameter("gcliters");//
            String gcamt = request.getParameter("gcamt");//
            String fleetliters = request.getParameter("fleetliters"); //
            String fleetamt = request.getParameter("fleetamt"); //
            String tappingliters = request.getParameter("tappingliters"); //
            String tappingamt = request.getParameter("tappingamt"); //
            String hosefillliters = request.getParameter("hosefillliters"); //
            String hosefillamt = request.getParameter("hosefillamt"); //
            String calibrateliters = request.getParameter("calibrateliters"); //
            String calibrateamt = request.getParameter("calibrateamt"); //
            String grossliters = request.getParameter("grossliters"); //
            String grossamt = request.getParameter("grossamt"); //
            String cashdepoamt = request.getParameter("cashdepoamt"); //           
            String checkdepoamt = request.getParameter("checkdepoamt"); //
            String variance = request.getParameter("variance"); //
            String cashier = request.getParameter("cashier"); //
            String nooftrans = request.getParameter("nooftrans"); //
            String tank1level = request.getParameter("tank1level"); //
            String tank1liters = request.getParameter("tank1liters"); //
            String tank2level = request.getParameter("tank2level"); //
            String createdate = request.getParameter("createdate"); //
            String userid = request.getParameter("userid"); //
            String transmit = request.getParameter("transmit"); //
            String transmitdate = request.getParameter("transmitdate"); //
            String tank2liters = request.getParameter("tank2liters"); //
            String product = request.getParameter("product"); //
            
            //Date dateTemp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            //String date = dateFormat.format(dateTemp.getTime());
            
            //String description = request.getParameter("description");
            //String detail = request.getParameter("detail");
            //String category = request.getParameter("category");
            //String image = request.getParameter("image");
            
            News n = new News(0, station, date, shift, uprice, cashliters, cashamt, cardliters, cardamt, chargeliters, chargeamt, gcliters, gcamt, fleetliters, fleetamt, tappingliters, tappingamt, hosefillliters, hosefillamt, calibrateliters, calibrateamt, grossliters, grossamt, cashdepoamt, checkdepoamt, variance, cashier, nooftrans, tank1level, tank1liters, tank2level, createdate, userid, transmit, transmitdate, tank2liters, product);
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            da.addNew(n);
            
            response.sendRedirect("/CRUD_News/AllPost");
        %>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't think there's something wrong with this other one but here.

**DataAccess.java**

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package dao;

import db.DBUtils;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import model.News;

/**
 *
 * @author Thang
 */
public class DataAccess {
    public void addNew(News n){
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = DBUtils.getPreparedStatement("insert into DailySales values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            //product
            ps.setString(1, n.getstation());
            ps.setString(2, n.getdate());
            ps.setString(3, n.getshift());
            ps.setString(4, n.getuprice());
            ps.setString(5, n.getcashliters());
            ps.setString(6, n.getcashamt());
            ps.setString(7, n.getcardliters());            
            ps.setString(8, n.getcardamt());
            ps.setString(9, n.getchargeliters());
            ps.setString(10, n.getchargeamt());
            ps.setString(11, n.getgcliters());
            ps.setString(12, n.getgcamt());
            ps.setString(13, n.getfleetliters());
            ps.setString(14, n.getfleetamt());
            ps.setString(15, n.gettappingliters());
            ps.setString(16, n.gettappingamt());
            ps.setString(17, n.gethosefillliters());
            ps.setString(18, n.gethosefillamt());
            ps.setString(19, n.getcalibrateliters());
            ps.setString(20, n.getcalibrateamt());
            ps.setString(21, n.getgrossliters());
            ps.setString(22, n.getgrossamt());
            ps.setString(23, n.getcashdepoamt());
            ps.setString(24, n.getcheckdepoamt());
            ps.setString(25, n.getvariance());
            ps.setString(26, n.getcashier());
            ps.setString(27, n.getnooftrans());
            ps.setString(28, n.gettank1level());
            ps.setString(29, n.gettank1liters());
            ps.setString(30, n.gettank2level());
            ps.setString(31, n.getcreatedate());
            ps.setString(32, n.getuserid());
            ps.setString(33, n.gettransmit());
            ps.setString(34, n.gettransmitdate());
            ps.setString(35, n.gettank2liters());             
            ps.setString(36, n.getproduct());             
           
            ps.executeUpdate();
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
//CHANGE LATER    
//CHANGE LATER
    //CHANGE LATER
    //CHANGE LATER
    //CHANGE LATER
    //CHANGE LATER//CHANGE LATER
    //CHANGE LATER
    
    public static List<News> getAll(){
        List<News> ls = new LinkedList<>();
        
        try {
            ResultSet rs = DBUtils.getPreparedStatement("select * from DailySales").executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                News n = new News(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14), rs.getString(15), rs.getString(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), rs.getString(19), rs.getString(20), rs.getString(21), rs.getString(22), rs.getString(23), rs.getString(24), rs.getString(25), rs.getString(26), rs.getString(27), rs.getString(28), rs.getString(29), rs.getString(30), rs.getString(31), rs.getString(32), rs.getString(33), rs.getString(34), rs.getString(35), rs.getString(36), rs.getString(37));
                ls.add(n);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
        return ls;
    }
    
    public static List<News> getNewById(int id){
        List<News> ls = new LinkedList<>();
        String sql = "select * from DailySales where dsId = " +id;
        try {
            ResultSet rs = DBUtils.getPreparedStatement(sql).executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                News n = new News(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14), rs.getString(15), rs.getString(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), rs.getString(19), rs.getString(20), rs.getString(21), rs.getString(22), rs.getString(23), rs.getString(24), rs.getString(25), rs.getString(26), rs.getString(27), rs.getString(28), rs.getString(29), rs.getString(30), rs.getString(31), rs.getString(32), rs.getString(33), rs.getString(34), rs.getString(35), rs.getString(36), rs.getString(37));
                ls.add(n);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
        return ls;
    }
    
    public void edit(int id, String station, String description, String date, String shift, String uprice, String cashliters, String cashamt, String cardliters, String cardamt, String chargeliters, String chargeamt, String gcliters, String gcamt, String fleetliters, String fleetamt, String tappingliters, String tappingamt, String hosefillliters, String hosefillamt, String calibrateliters, String calibrateamt, String grossliters, String grossamt, String cashdepoamt, String checkdepoamt, String variance, String cashier, String nooftrans, String tank1level, String tank1liters, String tank2level, String createdate, String userid, String transmit, String transmitdate, String tank2liters, String product){
        try {
            String sql = "update DailySales SET dsStnCode = ?, dsDate = ?, dsShift = ?, dsUPrice = ?, dsCashLiters = ?, dsCashAmt = ?, dsCardLiters = ?, dsCardAmt = ?, dsChargeLiters = ?, dsChargeAmt = ?, dsGCLiters = ?, dsGCAmt = ?, dsFleetLiters = ?, dsFleetAmt = ?, dsTappingLiters = ?, dsTappingAmt = ?, dsHosefillLiters = ?, dsHoseFillAmt = ?, dsCalibrateLiters = ?, dsCalibrateAmt = ?, dsGrossLiters = ?, dsGrossAmt = ?, dsCashDepoAmt = ?, dsCheckDepoAmt = ?, dsVariance = ?, dsCashier = ?, dsNoOfTrans = ?, dsTank1Level = ?, dsTank1Liters = ?, dsTank2Level = ?, dsCreateDate = ?, dsUserID = ?, dsTransmit = ?, dsTransmitDate = ?, dsTank2Liters = ?, dsProduct = ?" + " where id = ?";

            PreparedStatement ps= DBUtils.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, station);
            ps.setString(2, date);
            ps.setString(3, shift);
            ps.setString(4, uprice);
            ps.setString(5, cashliters);
            ps.setString(6, cashamt);
            ps.setString(7, cardliters);            
            ps.setString(8, cardamt);
            ps.setString(9, chargeliters);
            ps.setString(10, chargeamt);
            ps.setString(11, gcliters);
            ps.setString(12, gcamt);
            ps.setString(13, fleetliters);
            ps.setString(14, fleetamt);
            ps.setString(15, tappingliters);
            ps.setString(16, tappingamt);
            ps.setString(17, hosefillliters);
            ps.setString(18, hosefillamt);
            ps.setString(19, calibrateliters);
            ps.setString(20, calibrateamt);
            ps.setString(21, grossliters);
            ps.setString(22, grossamt);
            ps.setString(23, cashdepoamt);
            ps.setString(24, checkdepoamt);
            ps.setString(25, variance);
            ps.setString(26, cashier);
            ps.setString(27, nooftrans);
            ps.setString(28, tank1level);
            ps.setString(29, tank1liters);
            ps.setString(30, tank2level);
            ps.setString(31, createdate);
            ps.setString(32, userid);
            ps.setString(33, transmit);
            ps.setString(34, transmitdate);
            ps.setString(35, tank2liters);
            ps.setString(36, product);             
            ps.setInt(37, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }
    
    public void delete(int id){
        try {
            String sql = "delete DailySales where dsId = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = DBUtils.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any exception thrown?

Comment: Voted to close. 'Insert not Functioning' is not sufficiently detailed to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy - none, it's just that the insert won't happen like what it did just a few moments ago.

Comment: have you debuged your program? where does it stop execution?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I did, and it builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own problem, and it seems it's just a tad of carelessness on my part.

**AddNew.html**

```
            Shift: 
            <select name="shift">
                <option value="World">GY</option>
                <option value="World">AM</option>
                <option value="Tech">PM</option>
            </select><br><br>
```

I included option value "World" and "Tech" (which is part of the codes I found on the internet) even if the definition of the column "shift" on the database is varchar(2)

I'm sorry for taking your time over trivial matters. Have a good day.